# Svg icons disappear when I resize window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, sass, next.js

I have an SVG icon like this:

```
<svg width="19" height="19" viewBox="0 0 19 19" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <rect width="19" height="19" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
   <defs>
     <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
        <use xlinkHref="#image0" transform="scale(0.00444444)"/>
     </pattern>
     <image id="image0" width="225" height="225" xlinkHref="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"/>
   </defs>
</svg>
```

It displays on screen width > 1279 but disappears from the screen width <= 1279. Because of the page's layout, I have three divs that render on different screen sizes and contain this svg. I tried using svgs with different ids but the same content. However, it didn't work for me. Can somebody help me with that?

logic code:

component that uses svg icons (all of them disappear on width <= 1279 except star svgs that rendered in a list)

```
<div className="position__reviews--social-wrapper">
      <div className="position__reviews--social">
        <Icon className="position__reviews--social-icon" name="google" /> 
        <Icon className="position__reviews--social-icon" name="vivino" />
      </div>
      <div className="position__reviews--vivino-wrapper">
        <Icon className="position__reviews--vivino-text-icon" name="vivino-text" />
        {[...Array(5)].map((star,idx) => idx + 1 <= redStars ? <Icon className="position__reviews--star-red" name="position__review-star-red" /> : <Icon className="position__reviews--star-gray" name="position__review-star-gray" />)}
   </div>
</div>
```

Icon (svgIcons is a list of jsx items: `() => (<svg>...</svg>)` ):

```
const Icon = ({ name, fill, onClick, className }) => {
  const svg = svgIcons[name];

  const iconClasses = cn(className, {
    'icon--active': !!onClick,
  });

  return svg ? (
    <span className={iconClasses} onClick={onClick}>
      {svg(fill)}
    </span>
  ) : null;
};
```

css:

```
.position__reviews--social-icon {
  border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

What happens:

width > 1279:
[image: width > 1279]

width <= 1279:
[image: width <= 1279]

Comment: Please show your logic code instead a cod of svg

Comment: and you are 100% sure it is not a Media Query hiding content?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Yes. There is no css for hiding icons. Only icons disappear. Other elements are in their places.

Comment: I tested your Google icon, it is the most contrived code I have ever seen for **not** using an IMG element with a base64 dataURI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
<svg width="19" height="19" viewBox="0 0 19 19" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <rect width="19" height="19" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
   <defs>
     <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
        <use xlinkHref="#image0" transform="scale(0.00444444)"/>
     </pattern>
     <image id="image0" width="225" height="225" xlinkHref="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"/>
   </defs>
</svg>
```

was most likely created by a developer [in a K-Hole](https://www.verywellmind.com/what-is-a-k-hole-21861)

> "Falling into a k-hole" is slang for how it feels when you take a high enough dose of ketamine that your awareness of the world around you and your control over your own body become so profoundly impaired that you're temporarily unable to interact with others—or the world around you.

- It wraps a Base64 data (the Google G logo)
- in an `<image>`
- in a `<pattern>`
- in a `<rect>`
- in a `<svg>`

I would ask that developer what the meaning is, because all you have to do is:

- wrap the Base64 data in an IMG element

```
<img width="19" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxIPEBIQDw8PEBERFRAVEhAQFRAPFRIWFRUYFxYVFhUaHSggGBolGxUVIjEhJSkrLy4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGhAQGy0lICYtLS0tKy0vLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIAOEA4QMBEQACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAEAAgMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQYBAgcEA//EAEUQAAIBAQUCCAsFBgYDAAAAAAABAgMEBQYRITFREjJBYXGBkbETFiJCUlNyocHR0hQjYoKSBxckNJOyFUNjouHwM1TC/8QAGwEBAAIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQFAQMGAgf/xAAxEQEAAgECBQEGBQQDAAAAAAAAAQIDBBEFEiExUUEUFSJhcYETMjORoQYjsdFCUvH/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AO4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAwwNXNb0YZ2ljwsfSj2obnLPhnhLeZY2mGUww2DIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABq2GHgvK+qFmWdatCD9HbJ9EVqeLZK17ykYdNlyztSsyqtv/aJBZqz0JT/FVfAXTwVm37iNbVxHaFth4HeeuS2306oC2Y2tlTPKpGkt1OKXvebI9tVkn5LLHwfT17xv9URXvW0VOPaK8uZ1J5dmeRqnJafVMro8Fe1I/Z5Jty4zb6dTzvLfFKx2hrwFuRhnaH0p1ZR4spR9ltdx6i0x2l4nFS3eI/Z77Nf9qp8S1V+iU5TXZLNHuM16+rRfQafJ3pH+EzYsfWqH/kVOsudcB9sdPcba6u/r1QMvBMNvyTMSsl3Y+s9TJVlOg978uPate1EmmqpPfoq83Bs9Otfij5LNZbXCrFSpzjOL5YNSXuN9bRP5VXfHak7WjZ90enlkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhgRl835Rskc608m+LCPlTl0R+L0Nd8tad0nT6TLnnakfdz++8b2ivnGj9xT/AA6zfTLk6u0g5NVae3Z0Wl4Njx7Tk+Kf4VeUm22223tbebfSyLM791vWsVjasbMB6AAAAAAAAAHosVtq0JcOjUnTlvi8s+lbH1nqt5rPRqy6fHlja9Yld7ix/shbI5cnhoLT80eTpXYTceqjtdz+q4LMfFhnf5LxZ7TGpFThOM4y1UotNMmRO8bworVtSdrRs+qMvLIAAAAAAAAAAAw2BhsClYoxuqfCo2RxnNaSq7Yw5o+k/d0kPNqYr0r1Xeh4TOTa+XpHj1lz20V5VJOdSUpyltlJ5tkC1ptO8umx4646xWsbQ+Zh7AAAAAAAAAAAAAASdyX5WscuFSlnF8anLWMurkfOjbjy2pPRC1WgxaivxR18upXBiClbYZ03wZrj0pcaPzXOWWPLW8dHJ6rR5NPba0dPSUumbURkAAAAAAAABhsDWc0lm9Etr3A2c2xfi51nKhZpNUtkqi0dTeluj399fn1G+9YdNw3hcVj8XLHX0jwpxDXwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAS2GbFXrWiP2aThOOrq8kFve/o5Tdhrab9EDiGbFTDP4vX5OywWiz1eWr2Zls4ue7YMAAAAAAAAGGBzfHGJnVlKzUJfdp5VZrz2vNX4Vy7++BqM+/wANXScJ4dtEZsnf0/2pZCdAAAAAAAAABvDOwGAAAAAAAEhcl0VLZVVOkt3Dm+LBb38FymzFjm87Qi6vV009Oa37eXXLlumnZKSpUlptlJ8ab3tlrjxxSNocZqNRfPfnv/4kEj20MgAAAAAAAYzAqWPcQfZ6fgKUvvqq1a2wg9M+l6pdZF1ObkjljutuFaL8a/Pb8sfzLmBWuujwAAAAABtCDk1GKcm9iSbb6EZiN52h5taKxvPZZ7pwNaayUqvBoRfpeVN/lWzraJNNJe3foqdRxnDj6Ujmn+FosWArLBLwnhKz/FJwXZHIk10tIVGXjGot+Xp9EvRw5ZI6KyUPzQjPvzNsYqR6IdtZnt3vP7vtK5bM9HZbP/Tp/IzyV8PEajL/ANp/d47RhSx1Ntmpr2M6f9rR4nBSfRupr9TTteUJeH7PKUs3QqzpvkjPKpH4M030dZ7J+HjeWv6kRP8AlUL4w1abJm6lPhQ9ZT8uPXyx60RcmC1PoutNxLBn6RO0+JQ5pTwCQuS6KlsqqnSW5zm+LBb38FymzFjnJO0fuiavV009Oa32j1dcuW6KdkpKlSjzyk+NN72y1x0ikbQ43Uam+e/Pf/xIJHtoZAAAAAAAAAeS87bCz0p1qnFgm3z7kudvJdZ5taKxvLZixWy3ilfVxa8LbO0VZ1ajzlN5vm3JcyWhT3vN55pd1p8FcOOK1eY8twAAAAJjD2HqttllBcGmuPVlsXMvSfMbsWG1+3ZA1nEMemjr1nw6bceH6Njj91DOeXlVZazl18i5kWOPFWnZyup1mXUT8c9PCXRtRGQAAAAA1aB2VDEmCYVk6lmSpVdW4bIT+l9GneRMunifir3XOh4tfF8OTrX+YUe7bhr17Q7OoShKD+8ck0qa3v4b/eQ6Yb2tyx0X2bX4sWH8SJ337fN1i5bpp2SkqdJc8pPjTlyybLSmOKRtDj9RqL57ze8pBHtoZAAAAAAAAAAKvjHg1o/Z23lpKWTy18359hzfGOI2xZK46enWVrw2JpP4sd/Rza8bunQflaxeya2P5M8abVUzx06T6w6jDnrl+rxkv5t4AAAT2FMOyttTOWcaEH5c1tb9CPP3JkjDhnJPXsrOI6+unry1/N/j5usWSywowVOnFQhFZKK0SLKI2jaHIXva9ua07vuenkAAAAAAAAAfNQSbeSze16aj5ky3QGQAAAAAAAAADSpJJNvYs2zxe3JWbSzEbz0Um01nOcpvzm38vcfN9TmnLltefWXQYqclIq+FWmpJxkk09qeprpeaTvE7NsTMTvCtXrcrp5zp5yhyx2uPzRf6TiEZNq36T5WODVc3w26Shy033TQD23Rd07VWhRp7ZPWXJGK2yfQjZjpN7bQj6rUV0+Ob29PTy7LdthhZ6UaVJZRgslve9vnbLateWNocPmzWy3m9u8vWemsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARt/VuBRlvk1Fde33JlTxrN+FpbfPok6SnNkj5KmcIvGTAGYELetyKec6WUZcsdil8mWuj4jNPhydYTMGqmnS3ZW6kHFuMk01tT0aL6totG8TusotFo3h0v9nV0eCofaJLy63F5qaena9ews9Lj2rzT6uT4xqvxMv4cdq/5XDIlqgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAK/iiprCHtSfcvict/UeT8lPusuH16zKCOXWYYAAZY2ea03RG1SjF6SbSU1tS5elFjw7PkjLWleu8vftNsNJmHQbPSUIxhFZRikktySyR30RttDmbWm07y+p6YAAAABhgV++cWUrJVdGdOrJpRecFDLXpkibp9BkzV5q7I2XU1x25ZeHx/oeptHZS+o3+6c3mGv26niTx/oeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niTx/oeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niT94FD1No7KX1D3Tm8we3U8SfvAoeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niT94FD1No7KX1D3Tm8we3U8SfvAoeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niTx/oeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niTx/oeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niTx/oeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niTx/oeptHZS+oe6c/mD26niXuubFlK11fBQhVjLgylnNQyeWWmjeuvuI+fQ5MNea2z3i1VMk8sLCQ0oAAVXEU862W6MV8TiePW31O3iFxoI/towo00AADIksPUuFXT9FSfw+JdcBxc2p38dULXW2x7eVqyO3U7IAAAAAYYHMMffzsvYp9zOj4X+h91Rrf1FcLJDAAAAAAAAAAABNYOq8G20edyj2xaIXEK74LfZJ0s7ZYdZOXXQAAqF+P+In+X+1HB8ZnfV2+y70fTFDwlSlAAABN4Xj5VR80e9nTf05Hx3lW8QnpCxHWKwAAAAADDA5hj7+dl7FPuZ0nC/0PuqNZ+orhZIgAAAAAAAAAADAkMPyytdnf+rS98kiNq4/sWj5S24P1I+rsZya9AAFQvxfxE/y/2o4LjMbau32Xej/Sh4SrSgwAACbwu/KqLmj3s6f+nJ+K8K3iHp91iOrVgAAAAAGGBzDH387L2KfczpOF/ofdUaz9RXCyRAAAAAAAAAAAGB7blX8TQy9bS/uRo1X6V/pLZi/PH1dmORXwAAqmIY5V298Yv4HEcdptqt/MLnQz/bRpSJgAAASmHKnBrZelFrs1+DL3gGTl1E1n1hB19d8e60ZnaqhkAAAAAMMDmGPv52XsU+5nScK/Q+6o1n6iuFkiAAAAAAAAYAyADAkcOw4Vrs6/1ab7Hn8CNrZ2wX+jbp43yR9XYjk16AAK7iin5UJb012a/FnKf1Hi+Kl/ss+H27whDmVkGAAGYYns1/xGFmnCpN5ZSWi2tbHkujMseGY8k6itqek90DXanDhxzzz39F8hJNJrVPJo7+FTE7tzLIAAAAMMCjYtw5abTaXUpQjKDjBZuUY6pa6MudDrcWLFy2nrur9Tp75L7whvEy2eqj+uHzJnvPB5/hH9jyeDxMtnqo/rh8x7zwef4PY8ng8TLZ6qP64fMe88Hn+D2PJ4PEy2eqj+uHzHvPB5/g9jyeDxMtnqo/rh8x7zwef4PY8ng8TbZ6qP64fMe88Hn+GPY8nhGXpddWyyUK0VGUlmkpRlpnlyEnBqaZo3o1ZMVsfSzxEhrAAAwJ3BNHh26l+Hhy7ItfEgcSttgn57JOkjfLH7urHMrkAAReIaPCot8sGpfB95Tccw/iaWZ9a9UrR35cn1VY4ddhgDMMSjryvSNLyY5Snu5I9PyLTRcOvn+K3Sqn4hxamn+GnW38QrlatKcnKTbb5WdNixUxRtSNnIZs+TNbmyTu6XgW9fD2dU5P7yhlF88fMfZp+UscNt67T3W+izc9Np7wsxuTAAAAAAAAAAAAAMMDlGMrb4a2VGnmqeVNfl2/7nI6fhuLkwR8+ql1V+bJKEJ6OAAAYXD9m1nzrVqvoQjFdM3n/8lNxe/wANa+Vhoa/FNnQyiWYAA+dampRcXsaafWastIvSaz6s1tyzEwpFWm4ScXti2n1HzjPinHktSfSXQ0tFqxaGjeWr0S5TXWs2naGbWisbyg7yvnPOFF9M/p+Z0Gi4Vy7XzR9nMcQ4zNt6YJ+6FL2IiHNzO87ywZYSVwXrKyV41Vm47Jx9KL29fKug90vy23b9Pm/Cvu67Zq8asIzhJSjJJxa2NMnRO/V0FbRaN4fYy9AAAAAAAAAAAAicTXqrLZ5zz8trg01vk9j6tvUSNLgnNlivp6/Roz5Yx0mXI289XqzrYiIjaFJLBkAAADpmALH4OycN7aspS6l5Me5vrOY4lk588x46LfR02x7z6rOQEsAAAKtiuEaL8NLSMsk/aS07V3HK8Z4de+aL4479/wDadg1lcWKeeeyhXjecq2i8mHo7+d/I3aPh9MEbz1t/DndfxTJqJ2idq+PV4Cy7Krr6gAABZ8H4k+yy8DWb8BJ6Pb4OT5fZfL27zfiy7dJT9Jqfw55L9nS4TUknFpp6prVPrJS5id43bmWQAAAAAAAAB8bVaI04SnOSjGKblJ8iM1rNpisR1YtaKxvLlOJb6lbK3C1VOOapxfIuVvnfy3HUaLSxgptPee6kz5py26dkQTWkAAAw+tks8qtSFOHGnKMV1vLM15b/AIdJtPo91rNpisOz2SgqcI046RhGMV0JZHH3tNrc0r6teWIh9zy9AAAB4L6u6Nqozoy85aP0ZLWL6nkebV5o2as2OMleWXHrTQlSnKnNZSg2pLnRAmNp2c7as1tNZfIw8gAABkCwYaxRUsmUJ51KHo+dDni/h3cu3Hl5e6bptXbH0nrH+HSLuvKlaYKdGamuXLauaS2p9JLraLdlxjyVyRvWXsR6bAAAAAAMZgeK9L1pWaHDrTUVyLbKXNFbWY367NeTLXHG9pc1xHiOpbJZawop5xp7/wAUt79y950+i0dMUc3efP8ApU59ROWdo7IQsEcMAZAABcf2eXXw6krTJeTTzjDnk15T6k8vzFLxXUbRGKPrKfoce8zeXQcijWbIAAAAw0BS8fXFw19qpLyorKql50V53SuXm6CPmx7/ABQrddg3jnr93PyIqOwZAAAAAfex2upRlw6U5QkuWLy6nvXSZiZjs90yWpO9Z2W668fSjlG00lP8dPR9cXo+rI31z+Vjj4hMfnj9lmseKbJV2V4Rfo1Pu379DfGSsplNXit2slaVeM9YyjLni0+49bt8WifV9MzLO74VrZThx6lOOXpSjHvMc0eXmb1jvMIq2YuslL/OVR7qSdTPrWnvPE5aR6tN9Xir6qzemPKk842emqa9OflS6lsXXmabZ9+yDl4haelIVO1WmdWTnUnKcntlJ5v/AINFp5u6Be9rzvaXyRZaHieTTztbrXwxFpZOvwZ6Zq81JbNw3MgAD72GySr1IUqazlN5Lm3t8yWb6jVmyxipNp9HrHSbztDsF12GNnpQpQ2QWWe97W3zt5s5HLknJebT6r3HSKViIew8PYAAAAAGs457QxLmOL8OuzT8LSX3E3/Tb81827s6YeXHt1jsptXppxzzR2Vo0IAZAAAAADAA3kyM7yzE7NnJvRt9rG8s80+WuQ3ljcDAYAyAGSTptVkwX5qT9vLMTszmddouI4tRXxPj/TZE7hYPQJnubS6Tgm4fs8PDVV99UWie2nHd0vl7Dm+Iav8AFtyV/LH8yttLg5I3nutORWpjJkAAAAAAwwPnaKEakXCcVKMk1KL1TT5DHd5msTG0uYYow1KySc6ec6Dektrh+GXNuf8A1w8mLl6wpdVpJxTvHZXjUhAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAxIHut7UtFqjOZ1HD+LRk+DJ0ny21svODcLvONptEcssnSpy905LuQ1+ui39vHPT1lZ6XS7fFZekimWLJkAAAAAAAAMAa1KaknGSTTzTTSaae1NGJ692JjeNpUDEuDJQzq2ROUdsqO2UfY3rm27syNkw+tVVqdDt8WP9lNay0aya2p6ZEdWzEwwYYDIAAAAAAAAAAAABvSpSnJRhFylJ5KMU22+gREzPR6rWbTtEL/hfBypZVrUlKpo40tGoc8uRv3LnJePDt1lbabRRT4r9/C5JG9YsgAAAAAAAAAAAAYEFfuF6Nrzk14Or6yHL7S2S7+c13xVsi5tLTL8p8qBfGGrRZc3KHDp+sp5tda2x6yLbFaFTm0mTHPyQyNaMAAAAAAAAAAAMp+5sJ2i05ScXRpvz6iabX4Y7X3G2mG1u6Vh0eTJ17fVf7kuCjZI/dxzm+NUlrJ/JcyJVaRXst8Onrijp38pZHtvZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAatZhhCXphWzWjNun4Ob8+llB9a2PsNdsVZR8ulx5O8dVXt+Aqsc3QqwqL0Zp05duqfuNNtP4QcnD7/8JQNruG1UuPZ6uW+K4a7Y5mqcdo7wiW02SveJR0tHk9GuR6M8bbNO2zAYAGYG1KDm8oJye6Kcn2Icu7MVmeyUsmG7XV4tnqJb5rwa/wB2R7jFafRIrpctvSf8J6wYAm9a9aMFyxprhP8AU8kuxm2un8pWPh9v+crTdeG7NZsnTppzX+ZU8uXVyLqyN1cdYTsWmx4/ywl0bEhkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB8qtGM+NGMvaSfeYmHmaxPd5KlzWaXGs1B9NOD+B55K+Hj8HHPesNP8Asn/qWf+nD5Dkr4hj2fF/1j9n1p3VZ48Wz0Y9EIL4GYrHh6jFSO0PXCCiskkluWh6e4iI7Q3DIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGrMSxPdkxDIeoYkAwZefVsYewAAAAAAAAAAAAP/2Q==">
```

[image]

If you do want the contrived SVG, write proper SVG:

```html
<svg width="19" height="19" viewBox="0 0 19 19">
   <rect width="19" height="19" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
   <defs>
     <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
        <use href="#image0" transform="scale(0.00444444)"/>
     </pattern>
     <image id="image0" width="225" height="225" href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxIPEBIQDw8PEBERFRAVEhAQFRAPFRIWFRUYFxYVFhUaHSggGBolGxUVIjEhJSkrLy4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGhAQGy0lICYtLS0tKy0vLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIAOEA4QMBEQACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAEAAgMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQYBAgcEA//EAEUQAAIBAQUCCAsFBgYDAAAAAAABAgMEBQYRITFREjJBYXGBkbETFiJCUlNyocHR0hQjYoKSBxckNJOyFUNjouHwM1TC/8QAGwEBAAIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQFAQMGAgf/xAAxEQEAAgECBQEGBQQDAAAAAAAAAQIDBBEFEiExUUEUFSJhcYETMjORoQYjsdFCUvH/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AO4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAwwNXNb0YZ2ljwsfSj2obnLPhnhLeZY2mGUww2DIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABq2GHgvK+qFmWdatCD9HbJ9EVqeLZK17ykYdNlyztSsyqtv/aJBZqz0JT/FVfAXTwVm37iNbVxHaFth4HeeuS2306oC2Y2tlTPKpGkt1OKXvebI9tVkn5LLHwfT17xv9URXvW0VOPaK8uZ1J5dmeRqnJafVMro8Fe1I/Z5Jty4zb6dTzvLfFKx2hrwFuRhnaH0p1ZR4spR9ltdx6i0x2l4nFS3eI/Z77Nf9qp8S1V+iU5TXZLNHuM16+rRfQafJ3pH+EzYsfWqH/kVOsudcB9sdPcba6u/r1QMvBMNvyTMSsl3Y+s9TJVlOg978uPate1EmmqpPfoq83Bs9Otfij5LNZbXCrFSpzjOL5YNSXuN9bRP5VXfHak7WjZ90enlkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhgRl835Rskc608m+LCPlTl0R+L0Nd8tad0nT6TLnnakfdz++8b2ivnGj9xT/AA6zfTLk6u0g5NVae3Z0Wl4Njx7Tk+Kf4VeUm22223tbebfSyLM791vWsVjasbMB6AAAAAAAAAHosVtq0JcOjUnTlvi8s+lbH1nqt5rPRqy6fHlja9Yld7ix/shbI5cnhoLT80eTpXYTceqjtdz+q4LMfFhnf5LxZ7TGpFThOM4y1UotNMmRO8bworVtSdrRs+qMvLIAAAAAAAAAAAw2BhsClYoxuqfCo2RxnNaSq7Yw5o+k/d0kPNqYr0r1Xeh4TOTa+XpHj1lz20V5VJOdSUpyltlJ5tkC1ptO8umx4646xWsbQ+Zh7AAAAAAAAAAAAAASdyX5WscuFSlnF8anLWMurkfOjbjy2pPRC1WgxaivxR18upXBiClbYZ03wZrj0pcaPzXOWWPLW8dHJ6rR5NPba0dPSUumbURkAAAAAAAABhsDWc0lm9Etr3A2c2xfi51nKhZpNUtkqi0dTeluj399fn1G+9YdNw3hcVj8XLHX0jwpxDXwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAS2GbFXrWiP2aThOOrq8kFve/o5Tdhrab9EDiGbFTDP4vX5OywWiz1eWr2Zls4ue7YMAAAAAAAAGGBzfHGJnVlKzUJfdp5VZrz2vNX4Vy7++BqM+/wANXScJ4dtEZsnf0/2pZCdAAAAAAAAABvDOwGAAAAAAAEhcl0VLZVVOkt3Dm+LBb38FymzFjm87Qi6vV009Oa37eXXLlumnZKSpUlptlJ8ab3tlrjxxSNocZqNRfPfnv/4kEj20MgAAAAAAAYzAqWPcQfZ6fgKUvvqq1a2wg9M+l6pdZF1ObkjljutuFaL8a/Pb8sfzLmBWuujwAAAAABtCDk1GKcm9iSbb6EZiN52h5taKxvPZZ7pwNaayUqvBoRfpeVN/lWzraJNNJe3foqdRxnDj6Ujmn+FosWArLBLwnhKz/FJwXZHIk10tIVGXjGot+Xp9EvRw5ZI6KyUPzQjPvzNsYqR6IdtZnt3vP7vtK5bM9HZbP/Tp/IzyV8PEajL/ANp/d47RhSx1Ntmpr2M6f9rR4nBSfRupr9TTteUJeH7PKUs3QqzpvkjPKpH4M030dZ7J+HjeWv6kRP8AlUL4w1abJm6lPhQ9ZT8uPXyx60RcmC1PoutNxLBn6RO0+JQ5pTwCQuS6KlsqqnSW5zm+LBb38FymzFjnJO0fuiavV009Oa32j1dcuW6KdkpKlSjzyk+NN72y1x0ikbQ43Uam+e/Pf/xIJHtoZAAAAAAAAAeS87bCz0p1qnFgm3z7kudvJdZ5taKxvLZixWy3ilfVxa8LbO0VZ1ajzlN5vm3JcyWhT3vN55pd1p8FcOOK1eY8twAAAAJjD2HqttllBcGmuPVlsXMvSfMbsWG1+3ZA1nEMemjr1nw6bceH6Njj91DOeXlVZazl18i5kWOPFWnZyup1mXUT8c9PCXRtRGQAAAAA1aB2VDEmCYVk6lmSpVdW4bIT+l9GneRMunifir3XOh4tfF8OTrX+YUe7bhr17Q7OoShKD+8ck0qa3v4b/eQ6Yb2tyx0X2bX4sWH8SJ337fN1i5bpp2SkqdJc8pPjTlyybLSmOKRtDj9RqL57ze8pBHtoZAAAAAAAAAAKvjHg1o/Z23lpKWTy18359hzfGOI2xZK46enWVrw2JpP4sd/Rza8bunQflaxeya2P5M8abVUzx06T6w6jDnrl+rxkv5t4AAAT2FMOyttTOWcaEH5c1tb9CPP3JkjDhnJPXsrOI6+unry1/N/j5usWSywowVOnFQhFZKK0SLKI2jaHIXva9ua07vuenkAAAAAAAAAfNQSbeSze16aj5ky3QGQAAAAAAAAADSpJJNvYs2zxe3JWbSzEbz0Um01nOcpvzm38vcfN9TmnLltefWXQYqclIq+FWmpJxkk09qeprpeaTvE7NsTMTvCtXrcrp5zp5yhyx2uPzRf6TiEZNq36T5WODVc3w26Shy033TQD23Rd07VWhRp7ZPWXJGK2yfQjZjpN7bQj6rUV0+Ob29PTy7LdthhZ6UaVJZRgslve9vnbLateWNocPmzWy3m9u8vWemsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARt/VuBRlvk1Fde33JlTxrN+FpbfPok6SnNkj5KmcIvGTAGYELetyKec6WUZcsdil8mWuj4jNPhydYTMGqmnS3ZW6kHFuMk01tT0aL6totG8TusotFo3h0v9nV0eCofaJLy63F5qaena9ews9Lj2rzT6uT4xqvxMv4cdq/5XDIlqgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAK/iiprCHtSfcvict/UeT8lPusuH16zKCOXWYYAAZY2ea03RG1SjF6SbSU1tS5elFjw7PkjLWleu8vftNsNJmHQbPSUIxhFZRikktySyR30RttDmbWm07y+p6YAAAABhgV++cWUrJVdGdOrJpRecFDLXpkibp9BkzV5q7I2XU1x25ZeHx/oeptHZS+o3+6c3mGv26niTx/oeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niTx/oeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niT94FD1No7KX1D3Tm8we3U8SfvAoeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niT94FD1No7KX1D3Tm8we3U8SfvAoeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niTx/oeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niTx/oeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niTx/oeptHZS+oe6c3mD26niTx/oeptHZS+oe6c/mD26niXuubFlK11fBQhVjLgylnNQyeWWmjeuvuI+fQ5MNea2z3i1VMk8sLCQ0oAAVXEU862W6MV8TiePW31O3iFxoI/towo00AADIksPUuFXT9FSfw+JdcBxc2p38dULXW2x7eVqyO3U7IAAAAAYYHMMffzsvYp9zOj4X+h91Rrf1FcLJDAAAAAAAAAAABNYOq8G20edyj2xaIXEK74LfZJ0s7ZYdZOXXQAAqF+P+In+X+1HB8ZnfV2+y70fTFDwlSlAAABN4Xj5VR80e9nTf05Hx3lW8QnpCxHWKwAAAAADDA5hj7+dl7FPuZ0nC/0PuqNZ+orhZIgAAAAAAAAAADAkMPyytdnf+rS98kiNq4/sWj5S24P1I+rsZya9AAFQvxfxE/y/2o4LjMbau32Xej/Sh4SrSgwAACbwu/KqLmj3s6f+nJ+K8K3iHp91iOrVgAAAAAGGBzDH387L2KfczpOF/ofdUaz9RXCyRAAAAAAAAAAAGB7blX8TQy9bS/uRo1X6V/pLZi/PH1dmORXwAAqmIY5V298Yv4HEcdptqt/MLnQz/bRpSJgAAASmHKnBrZelFrs1+DL3gGTl1E1n1hB19d8e60ZnaqhkAAAAAMMDmGPv52XsU+5nScK/Q+6o1n6iuFkiAAAAAAAAYAyADAkcOw4Vrs6/1ab7Hn8CNrZ2wX+jbp43yR9XYjk16AAK7iin5UJb012a/FnKf1Hi+Kl/ss+H27whDmVkGAAGYYns1/xGFmnCpN5ZSWi2tbHkujMseGY8k6itqek90DXanDhxzzz39F8hJNJrVPJo7+FTE7tzLIAAAAMMCjYtw5abTaXUpQjKDjBZuUY6pa6MudDrcWLFy2nrur9Tp75L7whvEy2eqj+uHzJnvPB5/hH9jyeDxMtnqo/rh8x7zwef4PY8ng8TLZ6qP64fMe88Hn+D2PJ4PEy2eqj+uHzHvPB5/g9jyeDxMtnqo/rh8x7zwef4PY8ng8TbZ6qP64fMe88Hn+GPY8nhGXpddWyyUK0VGUlmkpRlpnlyEnBqaZo3o1ZMVsfSzxEhrAAAwJ3BNHh26l+Hhy7ItfEgcSttgn57JOkjfLH7urHMrkAAReIaPCot8sGpfB95Tccw/iaWZ9a9UrR35cn1VY4ddhgDMMSjryvSNLyY5Snu5I9PyLTRcOvn+K3Sqn4hxamn+GnW38QrlatKcnKTbb5WdNixUxRtSNnIZs+TNbmyTu6XgW9fD2dU5P7yhlF88fMfZp+UscNt67T3W+izc9Np7wsxuTAAAAAAAAAAAAAMMDlGMrb4a2VGnmqeVNfl2/7nI6fhuLkwR8+ql1V+bJKEJ6OAAAYXD9m1nzrVqvoQjFdM3n/8lNxe/wANa+Vhoa/FNnQyiWYAA+dampRcXsaafWastIvSaz6s1tyzEwpFWm4ScXti2n1HzjPinHktSfSXQ0tFqxaGjeWr0S5TXWs2naGbWisbyg7yvnPOFF9M/p+Z0Gi4Vy7XzR9nMcQ4zNt6YJ+6FL2IiHNzO87ywZYSVwXrKyV41Vm47Jx9KL29fKug90vy23b9Pm/Cvu67Zq8asIzhJSjJJxa2NMnRO/V0FbRaN4fYy9AAAAAAAAAAAAicTXqrLZ5zz8trg01vk9j6tvUSNLgnNlivp6/Roz5Yx0mXI289XqzrYiIjaFJLBkAAADpmALH4OycN7aspS6l5Me5vrOY4lk588x46LfR02x7z6rOQEsAAAKtiuEaL8NLSMsk/aS07V3HK8Z4de+aL4479/wDadg1lcWKeeeyhXjecq2i8mHo7+d/I3aPh9MEbz1t/DndfxTJqJ2idq+PV4Cy7Krr6gAABZ8H4k+yy8DWb8BJ6Pb4OT5fZfL27zfiy7dJT9Jqfw55L9nS4TUknFpp6prVPrJS5id43bmWQAAAAAAAAB8bVaI04SnOSjGKblJ8iM1rNpisR1YtaKxvLlOJb6lbK3C1VOOapxfIuVvnfy3HUaLSxgptPee6kz5py26dkQTWkAAAw+tks8qtSFOHGnKMV1vLM15b/AIdJtPo91rNpisOz2SgqcI046RhGMV0JZHH3tNrc0r6teWIh9zy9AAAB4L6u6Nqozoy85aP0ZLWL6nkebV5o2as2OMleWXHrTQlSnKnNZSg2pLnRAmNp2c7as1tNZfIw8gAABkCwYaxRUsmUJ51KHo+dDni/h3cu3Hl5e6bptXbH0nrH+HSLuvKlaYKdGamuXLauaS2p9JLraLdlxjyVyRvWXsR6bAAAAAAMZgeK9L1pWaHDrTUVyLbKXNFbWY367NeTLXHG9pc1xHiOpbJZawop5xp7/wAUt79y950+i0dMUc3efP8ApU59ROWdo7IQsEcMAZAABcf2eXXw6krTJeTTzjDnk15T6k8vzFLxXUbRGKPrKfoce8zeXQcijWbIAAAAw0BS8fXFw19qpLyorKql50V53SuXm6CPmx7/ABQrddg3jnr93PyIqOwZAAAAAfex2upRlw6U5QkuWLy6nvXSZiZjs90yWpO9Z2W668fSjlG00lP8dPR9cXo+rI31z+Vjj4hMfnj9lmseKbJV2V4Rfo1Pu379DfGSsplNXit2slaVeM9YyjLni0+49bt8WifV9MzLO74VrZThx6lOOXpSjHvMc0eXmb1jvMIq2YuslL/OVR7qSdTPrWnvPE5aR6tN9Xir6qzemPKk842emqa9OflS6lsXXmabZ9+yDl4haelIVO1WmdWTnUnKcntlJ5v/AINFp5u6Be9rzvaXyRZaHieTTztbrXwxFpZOvwZ6Zq81JbNw3MgAD72GySr1IUqazlN5Lm3t8yWb6jVmyxipNp9HrHSbztDsF12GNnpQpQ2QWWe97W3zt5s5HLknJebT6r3HSKViIew8PYAAAAAGs457QxLmOL8OuzT8LSX3E3/Tb81827s6YeXHt1jsptXppxzzR2Vo0IAZAAAAADAA3kyM7yzE7NnJvRt9rG8s80+WuQ3ljcDAYAyAGSTptVkwX5qT9vLMTszmddouI4tRXxPj/TZE7hYPQJnubS6Tgm4fs8PDVV99UWie2nHd0vl7Dm+Iav8AFtyV/LH8yttLg5I3nutORWpjJkAAAAAAwwPnaKEakXCcVKMk1KL1TT5DHd5msTG0uYYow1KySc6ec6Dektrh+GXNuf8A1w8mLl6wpdVpJxTvHZXjUhAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAxIHut7UtFqjOZ1HD+LRk+DJ0ny21svODcLvONptEcssnSpy905LuQ1+ui39vHPT1lZ6XS7fFZekimWLJkAAAAAAAAMAa1KaknGSTTzTTSaae1NGJ692JjeNpUDEuDJQzq2ROUdsqO2UfY3rm27syNkw+tVVqdDt8WP9lNay0aya2p6ZEdWzEwwYYDIAAAAAAAAAAAABvSpSnJRhFylJ5KMU22+gREzPR6rWbTtEL/hfBypZVrUlKpo40tGoc8uRv3LnJePDt1lbabRRT4r9/C5JG9YsgAAAAAAAAAAAAYEFfuF6Nrzk14Or6yHL7S2S7+c13xVsi5tLTL8p8qBfGGrRZc3KHDp+sp5tda2x6yLbFaFTm0mTHPyQyNaMAAAAAAAAAAAMp+5sJ2i05ScXRpvz6iabX4Y7X3G2mG1u6Vh0eTJ17fVf7kuCjZI/dxzm+NUlrJ/JcyJVaRXst8Onrijp38pZHtvZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAatZhhCXphWzWjNun4Ob8+llB9a2PsNdsVZR8ulx5O8dVXt+Aqsc3QqwqL0Zp05duqfuNNtP4QcnD7/8JQNruG1UuPZ6uW+K4a7Y5mqcdo7wiW02SveJR0tHk9GuR6M8bbNO2zAYAGYG1KDm8oJye6Kcn2Icu7MVmeyUsmG7XV4tnqJb5rwa/wB2R7jFafRIrpctvSf8J6wYAm9a9aMFyxprhP8AU8kuxm2un8pWPh9v+crTdeG7NZsnTppzX+ZU8uXVyLqyN1cdYTsWmx4/ywl0bEhkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB8qtGM+NGMvaSfeYmHmaxPd5KlzWaXGs1B9NOD+B55K+Hj8HHPesNP8Asn/qWf+nD5Dkr4hj2fF/1j9n1p3VZ48Wz0Y9EIL4GYrHh6jFSO0PXCCiskkluWh6e4iI7Q3DIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGrMSxPdkxDIeoYkAwZefVsYewAAAAAAAAAAAAP/2Q=="/>
   </defs>
</svg>
```